# APC UPS old configuration file found. How to resolve?

Tags: 20.04, intel, intel-nuc, ups

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-125-generic x86_64) on an Intel NUC and have a APC UPS hooked up to it. I just experienced a power outage and, while the UPS worked as expected during the outage, after running `apcaccess`I received the below Warning at the top of the UPC stats. Is this something I need to address? If so, how do I go about updating?

```
: Warning: old configuration file found.

: Expected: "## apcupsd.conf v1.1 ##"
: Found:    "
"

: Please check new file format and
: modify accordingly the first line
: of config file.
```

Comment: Sounds like a question for APC as it is their software.

Comment: Good call. Thanks